# Android Action Bar Title Text not clickable on certain phones

Tags: java, android, user-interface, actionbarsherlock

I have a project that I am currently updating. In previous versions I have been able to select the title text, and it would react as part of the back button in the action bar. I currently have no icon in the actionbar by design and in previous versions the text was still interactive.

I tried implementing different layouts for varying screen sizes, however, since then on normal and small screen sized phones (tested: [Samsung Galaxy S III Mini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S_III_Mini) and [Sony Xperia tipo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia_tipo)) now only the back button ("<") reacts to touch.

The title text is still clickable on an [Samsung Galaxy S4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S4) and a [Nexus 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_4). I have reverted the code back to how it was before I made those changes, along with trying code from last week to make sure nothing has changed, and the bug still occurs. I have tried other apps on the Samsung Galaxy S III Mini and the text in RedReader is clickable, so it's definitely app side, but I am not sure what has changed that will cause this.

I am currently at a loss as to why it is doing it. I've also attempted to update ActionBarSherlock to see if that may have caused an issue, but I am not sure what to try next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Title on `ActionBar` is clickable from `4.2.2` version of Android. Before only < or icon.

Comment: That makes sense, it must have slipped under the radar as it is this version where I have removed the icon. Will look at replacing the back button icon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the need to implement this functionality in previous versions (including versions 2.x), you can use the ActionBarSherlock.

The library will automatically use the native action bar when appropriate or will automatically wrap a custom implementation around your layouts. This allows you to easily develop an application with an action bar for every version of Android from 2.x and up.

Visit http://actionbarsherlock.com/